# Which Hadoop release fits RHive requirements

Tags: java, r, hadoop, versioning, hive

I try to install RHive.
According requirements, RHive needs Hadoop core >= 0.20.3

(See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHive/)

When I go to Apache Hadoop releases, there is no 0.20.3 release...

(See http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html)

Then, which Hadoop releases fit RHive requirements?

Comment: It says `>= 0.20.3` that means anything above that release version should be fine. In general I would go for the latest stable release unless there is a documented reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHive does not work with YARN, then any release BEFORE YARN is good.
I tested with Hadoop 0.20.205.0, it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest stable. 1.0.3

Or I would personally recommend cdh4, cloudera's version of hadoop.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/02/introducing-cdh4/